# Delete Old Emails From Shared Mailbox that contains over 300K items

Tags: vba, outlook

I need to permanently delete emails from a shared mailbox that are older than a certain age.

The AutoArchive function does not affect the shared mailbox, and every time I try to run a rule to do this, it fails and does not take any action.
I've been manually clearing hundreds of emails from which takes an absolute age (when you have over 300k sitting in there), as it fills up my own deleted items when I do.

Edit:
I've been chopping up random bits of code I've found to try and achieve this. I have access to 6 other shared mailboxes within my department. I've been looking at the GetSharedDefaultFolder function but it is not very well explained and normally errors when my bodged attempt runs. I am not sure what it wants in the recipient function, as I have tried the mailbox name and address. The MS online resources aren't very helpful in this case:

Edit 2:
I have edited my code to the below. In this version I get an Overflow error on the line `For intCount = olSharedBox.Items.Count To 1 Step -1`.
Since there are over 300k emails in that box I think it is now looking at the right thing but not sure of a way around it. Is it not possible to get the current number from the pre-counted figure that appears next to the inbox?

```
Sub DeleteOldSharedMail()

Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
Dim olNS As Outlook.NameSpace
Dim olMailItem As Outlook.MailItem
Dim objVariant As Variant
Dim lngMovedItems As Long
Dim intCount As Integer
Dim intDateDiff As Integer
Dim olSharedBox As Folder
Dim mbOwner As Outlook.Recipient


Set olApp = Outlook.Application
Set olNS = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set mbOwner = olNS.CreateRecipient("mailbox@email.com")
Set olSharedBox = olNS.GetSharedDefaultFolder(mbOwner, olFolderInbox)
  
For intCount = olSharedBox.Items.Count To 1 Step -1
    Set objVariant = olSharedBox.Items.Item(intCount)
    DoEvents
    If objVariant.Class = olMail Then
        
         intDateDiff = DateDiff("d", objVariant.SentOn, Now)
         
        ' Set number of days
        If intDateDiff > 180 Then
          objVariant.Delete
          Call ClearDeletedFolder ' Working. Will change to call every 100 emails deleted after first run.
          
          'count the # of items moved
           lngMovedItems = lngMovedItems + 1
        
        ' No need to run the IF statement on the rest of the mailbox assuming the macro runs from oldest to newest.
        'Else: GoTo Marker
        
        End If
    End If
Next

' Display the number of items that were moved.
Marker:
MsgBox "Moved " & lngMovedItems & " messages(s)."
End Sub
```

Comment: Which office are you running? Is there anything that have tried you can share?

Comment: I'm using Office 2013 and have edited my question to include a first attempt, gathering what I can from other resources. I miss excel VBA. Outlook seems so strange in comparison.

Comment: Dim intCount As Long

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the NameSpace.GetSharedDefaultFolder method to get at the Inbox to delete items.  However, if the items are in another folder you will need Full Mailbox access to that mailbox or write permissions on the specific folders.  In those cases you will need to find the folders in that mailbox IF that mailbox has also been added to the current Outlook profile.  Then you can access the folders from the matching Store object in NameSpace.Stores (e.g. via Store.GetDefaultFolder or .GetRootFolder, then "walk" through Folder.Folders collections).

Regardless, there is on way to permanently delete an email immediately in the Outlook Object Model.  But you can delete it twice if you find it again in the Deleted Items folder.

See also:
[How to: Delete All Items and Subfolders in the Deleted Items Folder](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb960906(v=office.12).aspx)

Comment: The deletion code runs smoothly and I have put a call in to trigger it after every email that is deleted from the mailbox. I know it's inefficient but the first time I run this it will probably delete about 100k emails, and they won't fit in my deleted items ^_^

I have edited my answer to include my first attempt. I am struggling to understand the method you stated as online documentation is not very friendly and other code examples are very varied in its use.

Comment: You seem to be using GetSharedDefaultFolder correctly; are you certain you have edit/delete rights in that user's Inbox? BTW, change intCount to a Long, as an Integer in VBA has maximum value of 32767

Comment: It took me a while to understand it after hunting for a couple examples. The MSDN site also takes forever and a day to load on my work network for some reason too. But it seems like you and niton were correct about the interger! As soon as I changed it to Long I was able to step through the entire thing just fine. Thanks very much.